# custom msg in pub/sub node

Tags: ros, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Want to implement user defined msg in nodes**
I edited CMakeLists.txt to include rosbuild_genmsg().

In the publisher/subscriber node, do I have to include it like in the case of std_msg? (i.e. #include "msg/custom_msg.h" or something?)

Will this correspond to the following change:
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise**msg::custom_msg**("chatter", 1000);

Further, I want to create a subscriber node, and publish messages to it manually, should the corresponding callback method be modified as:

void chatterCallback(const **msg::custom_msg**::ConstPtr& msg)
{
ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}

Thanks a lot, really appreciate your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29097/custom-msg-in-pub/sub-node/) by [kshitij](https://answers.ros.org/users/1481/kshitij/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2012-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you use as **msg** should be the package name.

Otherwise it should work.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1